# Adding heat to a particle system and taking that into account in Newtons equations

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, thermodynamics

Suppose I'm looking at a particle system in a $2D$ box, with $N$ particles with position $(x_i(t),y_i(t))\; i=1,..,N$. Lets assume I know the temperature at any point in the box at any time $T(x,y,t)$. The motion can be described by Newton's equations:

$$m_i \frac{d^2x_i}{dt^2} = - \frac{ \partial U_i}{ \partial x_i}\\ m_i \frac{d^2y_i}{dt^2} = - \frac{ \partial U_i}{ \partial y_i}$$

My question is if I know the $T(x,y,t)$, how do I convert it into the potential energy function $U_i$ for each particle, I know the first law of thermodynamics must be the key here but I can't figure out how to do it.

Thanks a lot for the help in advance.

Comment: There is a  typo in your equation, it should be $m_i\frac {d^2 x_i}{dt^2}=..., m_i\frac {d^2 y_i}{dt^2}=...$

Comment: @AlexTrounev Thanks I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to do it is to convert the Newton equations to [Langevin equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langevin_equation), which are  [stochastic differential equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_differential_equation). Langevin modeled the heat bath as having two effects on the system - the mean deterministic dissipative term and random stochastic fluctuations. ([Later theoretical treatment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zwanzig_projection_operator) supported its original intuitive derivation) Einstein gave the constrain on the [fluctuating and dissipating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluctuation-dissipation_theorem) terms to describe thermal equilibrium (by using the equipartition). So in general, the Langeving equations for a particle are ($p$ and $x$ can bevectors, the rest are constants)-
$$\dot{x}=\frac{p}{m}\\
\dot{p}=-\nabla U -
\gamma p+\sqrt{2D_p}\xi(t)$$
Here $\gamma$ describes the mean dissipation, $D_p$ is the momentum diffusion coefficient and $\xi$ is random Gaussian variable ([process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_process)), with zero mean and unit variance. These equations are Newton like equations that incorporate random forces of the bath on the particle. At thermal equilibrium, the Einstein relation imposes the following connection -
$$D_p=\gamma m k_B T$$
With $D_p$ and $\gamma$ constants, $k_B$ is the Boltzmann constant and $T$ is the temperature. (you may find different definition - using the position diffusion coefficient, that reads as $\gamma m D_x=k_B T$, as the subscript $x$ or $p$ droppedin many cases. Distinguish by dimensional analysis).

Note on thermal equilibrium. There are several definitions for thermal equilibrium, however the most general, fundamental and accepted is the notion of [detailed balance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Detailed_balance), that translated to time in variance of the system. Using Einstein relation in Langevin equation for some potential $U$ satisfies detailed balance at the system's steady state (if it has a steady state! For example diffusion in flat potential has no steady state, thus doesn't describe equilibrium, however use of Einstein relation implies coupling of the system to thermal bath).
Modification of Einstein relation to be coordinate dependent still satisfies detailed balance! (it's still a solution the Kramer-[Fokker-Planck equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fokker%E2%80%93Planck_equation))That is, use of -
$$D_p(x,p,t) = \gamma(x,p,t)mk_BT(x,p,t)$$

You can interpret the equation above in several ways. Strictly speaking, temperature is defined only for global equilibrium, when the value of $T$ is uniform thru ought the system. Interpretation to out of equilibrium is not unique. For example, should $\gamma$ or $D_p$ or both have coordinate dependence? Usually you must have closer look on your system and make the proper modeling). One common use would be to use constant $\gamma$, thus the equations read -
$$\dot{x}=\frac{p}{m}\\
\dot{p}=-\nabla U -
\gamma p+\sqrt{2\gamma m k_B T(x,p,t)}\xi(t)$$

When the diffusion coefficient is coordinate dependent, it's called [multiplicative noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_noise), and special [care should be taken during the solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratonovich_integral#Numerical_methods). So we got Newton-like equation for particle's position and momentum, that integrates the effect of thermal bath as random forces. In your case $T(x,p,t)=T(x,t)$

Incorporation of Fick's law, with $J\propto -\nabla T(x,t)$ into Newton's equations would be much more rudimentary approach that will allow to define some "potential" force acting on the particle due to thermal gradients. This approach however is misleading, since in this case the flow is of energy (heat) and not particles. Proper way to do it is to write the Fokker-Planck equation and identify the extra terms poping out after standard coordinate transformation ($\propto \frac{\partial D_p}{\partial x} \propto \frac{\partial T}{\partial x}$) as effective thermal force. In this case the "force" is ensemble averaged, and non vanishing only in presence of thermal gradients (not strict equilibrium).

Comment: First off, thanks a lot for a great, well written, and complete response. So in your write up $U$ is just all the other sources of potential energy for the particle right?

Comment: $-\nabla U$ incapsulates all the "Newtonian" forces (not necessarily conservative), unrelated to heat bath. Notice that this is a non-interacting theory. Interacting theory demands much more effort.